# Can I apply for citizenship in 2 year and 9 , even though I have multiple trips out of state less than 5 month,or do I have to wait an additional 5

Tags: us-citizens

Can I apply for citizenship in 2 year and 9 months, even though I had 4 trip out of state less than 6 month or do I have to wait an additional 6 months before applying for citizenship?

Comment: 2 years and 9 months from what event?  By "out of state" did you mean "out of the United States"?  The question is unclear.  Can you edit it and mention when you became a permanent resident and, if you are married to a US citizen, when you were married, along with the timing and duration of the trips you took outside the US?

Comment: 2 year and 9 months after I got my green card and I’m married to a US citizen(require 3 years to become an US citizens after marriage with an US citizen)

Comment: @Sanaz: You have been married for more than 3 years? Your spouse has been a US citizen for more than 3 years? Have you been physically present in the US for 1.5 years cumulatively since you have gotten your green card?

Comment: Out of your state of residence or out of the country?